# pset4 speller using trie. Problem with the size function

Tags: c, cs50, trie

i was working on pset4 speller using trie. i wanted to use recursion to find the size of the dictionary loaded. But nothing is working. According to what debugger is doing, i think that it is probably not returning to what sizer was pointing previously. For example in a dictionary of :

```
a
aa
aab
ab
```

the size is able to read the first three. but when i am returning the counter to the previous size, it does not read the letter b after a. I think it is still checking the array in  which it is reading aab. what can i do ???

```
unsigned int size(void)
{
    int ctr = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
            if (sizer -> children[i] == NULL)
            {
                continue;

            }
            else
            {
                // do i need to use a pointer here to point 
                                // to sizer before changing it

                sizer = sizer -> children[i];
                if ((sizer -> is_word) == true)
                {
                    ctr ++;
                }

                int x = size();
                ctr += x;

            }

    }
    // Before returning ctr should i use the pointer to change sizer to     
    // what it was previously . Can it work???

    return ctr;
}
```

Comment: You might try another approach. Since all the words are processed by `load`, perhaps "count" them in that function. Then `size` can simply return the count.

Comment: thnx i did that , it just never crossed my mind that it could be that easy. But i was also able to fix my size() function and now i also works totally fine with recursion

Comment: The signature: `unsigned int size(void)` says that the returned value is `unsigned int`.  However the variable `x` is declared as: `int` which is a signed value.  So there is a mismatch.

Comment: the signature: `unsigned int size(void)` says that the returned value is `unsigned int`.  However, the variable `ctr` is declared as `int`, so there is a mismatch.

Comment: but i think that i am pretty sure ( for all practical reasons in context of the problem) that counter will never be negative and not reach the cap value of int( which is probably not a problem as it will still be in the domain of unsigned int and it would be valid to return it) . But definitely yeah it is a mismatch; better to set ctr as an unsigned int....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think it is still checking the array in which it is reading aab. what can i do ???

I think you're right.

Consider how you update the value of global variable `sizer` in this code.  The only way you ever do that is this:

```
sizer = sizer -> children[i];
```

Since you only ever set `sizer` to point to one of the children of the current node, never restoring it to a previous value, the program follows exactly one path from the root to a leaf, and then it's exhausted its capabilities.  With different inputs you can demonstrate for yourself that this is what is happening.  For example,

```
a
b
ba
```

will report a count of 1, since it traverses node "a" first, and it's a leaf.

Global variables can very easily get you into trouble, especially modifiable ones.  Start now cultivating a habit of avoiding their use.  Prefer to convey information to functions via arguments, instead.

Also prefer to avoid recursion under most circumstances, and don't even consider combining recursion with modifiable global variables until you have a lot more experience (which at that point will tell you "I want no part of that").

It's unclear what is the type of `sizer`, but suppose it is `struct sizer *`.  In that case, consider what other changes would be needed to change the function signature to

```
unsigned int size(const struct sizer *node_sizer);
```

That's not just a style thing.  Done properly, it will resolve your functional issue, too.

Comment: Super thanks for the answer . But the problem specifies that i have to use the prototype given by them which is unsigned int size(void). However I am free to add local or global variables to them

Comment: Then don't recurse, @CeNiEi.  Or don't make *that* function recursive, but instead let it wrap a different recursive function with the signature you choose.